# Append a new row to a table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code trying to append a new row to jquery but it's not working.

```
$('#search-results > tbody').append('<tr><td data-th="Name">Test</td><td data-th="Email">test@test.com</td><td data-th="Phone Number">07777777777</td><td data-th="Car Reg.">ocf83or</td><td data-th="Time">1pm</td></tr>');
```

My table is setup like so:

```
<table class="view-bookings-table mobile-optimised hidden" id="search-results">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
            <th scope="col">Phone Number</th>
            <th scope="col">Car Reg.</th>
            <th scope="col">Time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

My full code is actually:

```
$('#search').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#search-results > tbody').append('<tr><td data-th="Name">Test</td><td data-th="Email">test@test.com</td><td data-th="Phone Number">07777777777</td><td data-th="Car Reg.">ocf83or</td><td data-th="Time">1pm</td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: [Your code works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/eestho47/). Did you include jQuery? And where/when is this script being called?

Comment: I have just added my full code as it's wrapped within a submit which maybe has something to do with it?

Comment: Your code i already working if you use submit it should be place inside a form with an id search. 

Or try make it onclick first via button just to test your code.

Comment: Seems to work fine? http://jsfiddle.net/n2L9t6qf/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine and works well with every possible version of jQuery.

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ydn2k14h/1/)

You may have a jQuery error somewhere else on your page or you are not loading it. Also what is

```
class='hidden'
```

doing? Maybe it's just a css issue?